# Anonymous function in dynamic list being passed same parameter value

Tags: javascript

I'm building a `<ul>` dynamically within an object array where each list item calls a function when a link is clicked. However, the function is only ever being passed the parameter from the last item in the object array. Here is my code...

```
var list = document.createElement("ul");
var object;

for (var i = 0; i < myObjects.length; i++)
{
    object = myObjects[i];

    listItem = document.createElement("li");
    image = document.createElement("img");
    image.setAttribute("src", object.image_url)
    listItem.appendChild(image);
    listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(object.title));

    link.setAttribute("href", "#");
    link.addEventListener("click", function(){someFunction(object.id);}, false);
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click Me!"));
    listItem.appendChild(link);

    list.appendChild(listItem);
}

element.appendChild(list);
```

All the variables are declared within this same function, so no globals are used. Before anyone suggests it, I'm not using jQuery because I'm trying to get my head round the basics of javascript before I move on to using any libraries.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Mister B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way scope works, the anonymous function has a reference to the *variable*, not to its *value*. When you change that variable later, the change is reflected in the anon function.

Perhaps using a closure trick could work?

Change

```
link.addEventListener("click", function(){someFunction(object.id);}, false);
```

To

```
(function(O) {
   link.addEventListener("click", function(){someFunction(O.id);}, false);
})(object);
```

If I'm not mistaken, that oughta create a new variable, whose value will be unaffected by subsequent changes to `object` in the `for` loop.

Comment: Genius, thanks very much. I knew it had something to do with closure but couldn't quite grasp it, now I do. Just out of interest, why do I need to wrap the outer function in parenthesis?

Comment: I'm not sure that you *do* need to wrap the outer function in parentheses, but the parentheses at the end ( `...(object);` ) are required. I just like to wrap the whole function to be on the safe side, as older versions of IE have thrown weird errors at me for not wrapping things before.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, this is a classic closure issue.

You'll need to pass in the `object.id` to a wrapper function, like this:

```
(function(id) {
   link.addEventListener("click", function(){someFunction(id);}, false);
})(object.id);
```